# Skipping lines while iterating over a vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

So I made a `vector<string>` of lines I read in from a textfile. The thing is these lines make up small sets of data. What I want to do is basically iterate over these blocks of data. (Which can be either 3 or 4 lines each. We can tell by seeing what the 2nd line has).

> Some sample data can be like this:
>
> Link
>
> 1
>
> Apple

or

> Link
>
> 2
>
> Apple
>
> Banana

Currently what I tried to do is the following:

```
for(vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i != records.size(); i++){
    cout << "Test << endl;
    string a = records[i];
    string b = records[i+1];
    string c = records[i+2];
    i += 3;
}
```

Basically I'm trying to make the `i` jump from name to name, regardless of if it's a 3 or 4 line block.

However for probably obvious reasons, this doesn't work. Question is:

> How do I iterate over a vector so I can jump lines, but it won't be iterating/trying to go through every line anyways and causes an error?

Because right now when I try and do this (only using a test case of 2, 3 lined records) and it doesn't work. I should only be reading using that loop twice, but I read in like way more than that, somehow. So how do I fix it?

Comment: What happens if `i+1` or `i+2` is greater than `records.size()`?

Comment: Why do you increase `i` by three *inside* the loop? That means each iteration it will increase by *four*. Why not just do e.g. `i += 3` in the actual loop statement?

Comment: For starters, if your text file isn't exactly a multiple of 4 lines long, you're going to have buffer overrun problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Because it can vary by either 3, or by 4?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `(Which can be either 3 or 4 lines each.)`

Comment: So you don't *know* beforehand how much you need to increment the `i` variable? Then why *always* increment it by four? How *do* you know how much to increment the index?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The thing is, let me edit it, but basically one of the  lines ( the second one) indicates if there is 1 or 2 lines following it that are part of the record.

Comment: Right now I was just showing a small example

Comment: I would refactor this.  I would make a `Record` class and you store all the related string in the `Record`.  Then you have a vector of `Records`.  Then it makes it really easy to traverse the records.

Comment: For us to understand the whole problem, it's is important that we can see  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And that all relevant information is included in the body of the question. And if you have "errors" it's important that we get to know *what* those "errors" are. *How* "it doesn't work".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I believe I just did that.

Comment: Wow... quite shocking to get this question from a dude with 3500 rep points...

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Rep has what to do with this?

Comment: With all due respect, your problem can be solved by decent use of a debugger... your question should come from someone with 1 rep point... maybe 11 points... 200 points would already be shocking.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist That's just bad thinking.

Comment: Not really. Honestly, I've been on stackoverflow for 5+ years. You're like the second incident I recall that does this with 3000+ points. Don't get offended. Try to learn from this and improve your questions.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Really? Why does rep-question have to be an issue? This is a community that thrives on helping each other, not to  become an inquisitor and judge...

Comment: @Santiago don't start with that wishful thinking with me. There's no community in the world that's more judgmental than stackoverflow, yet this is not why I said what I said. I'm trying to help. This question is BAD by all standards of SO. Period! The code doesn't even compile. Please take that attitude with those -1ing questions of new users without even having the courtesy to leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you need to make sure your loop doesn't overrun and go out of bounds. That is simply done by changing the condition to make sure the index is *less* than the size of the vector.

Then you need to actually get the number of valid "lines" in the vector, by converting the second line into a number that you use to get the remaining data.

Considering your input I would do something like this:

```
for(vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < records.size(); /* note no increment */){
    string name = records[i];
    unsigned long count = stoul(records[i + 1]);

    for (unsigned long j = 0; j < count && i + j < records.size(); ++j){
        // Read and do something with records[i + j]
    }

    i += 2 + count;
}
```

Note that you should probably check that the size of `records` is at least `2` before entering the outer loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out with this. For some reason it didn't occur to me that I could just not have an increment. +1 and accepted.

Comment: You can also put count in the first statement of the for, and do the increment in the loop definition, i.e. `for(vector<string>::size_type i = 0, count = 0; i+1 < records.size(); i += 2 + count)`

Answer (score 0):

An iterator-based alternative, based on @Someprogrammerdude's answer.

```
typedef vector<string>::const_iterator iterator;
for (iterator it = records.begin(); records.end() - it > 1; /* note no increment */)
{
    string name = *it++;
    unsigned long count = stoul(*it++);

    for (; count && it != records.end(); --count, ++it){
        // Read and do something with *it
    }
}
```